# Перебор массива с выбором по N элементов на каждой итерации

Tags: php

Есть неассоциативный массив, его размер и значения заранее известны. Как сделать перебор значений массива, выбирая на каждой итерации N различных элементов? Иными словами, надо выбрать все возможные последовательности из N элементов массива. При этом важен порядок элементов, т.е. (1,2) и (2,1) считаются разными последовательностями.

Например:

```
$arr = [1,2,3,4];
$N = 2;

$seq = getSequenses($N, $arr);
```

> $seq = [(1,2) (1,3) (1,4) (2,1) (2,3) (2,4) ... (4,3)];

getSequenses возвращает массив последовательностей.

N может быть любым целым числом в диапазоне `[0 .. length($arr)]`.

PS: да, это по-сути долго, но скорость не критична.

Comment: размер массива может быть больше 32?

Comment: @Sergiks на практике нет, но в теории - да. почему это важно?

Comment: можно элегантно использовать битовые операции

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задачу разбиваем на две:

1. выборка $N элементов из массива без учета порядка, важен сам набор;
2. перемешивание очередных $N элементов между собой всеми способами.

Для первой подзадачи можно (неоптимально!) пройти от `0` до `2^L` (L - длина исходного массива) и считать включенные биты. Нужно чтобы их было ровно N.

Для второй используем рекурсивную ф-ю. Перебираем позиции. На очередной пробуем все доступные значения, а хвост отправляем на следующий виток рекурсии этой же ф-ии.

Примерно так ([Ideone](http://ideone.com/0XfUkI)):

```
test();

function joiner($a) { return join(', ', $a); }
function test() {
    $r = getSequenses( 3, ['a','b','c','d']);
    print_r( array_map( 'joiner', $r));
}

function getSequenses( $N, $arr) {
    $L = count($arr);
    if( $L > 32) throw new Exception("Массив длиннее 32 элементов");
    $result = [];

    for( $i=0; $i<pow( 2, $L); $i++) {
        if( $N != countBits( $i)) continue;

        // get all permutations
        $set = array();
        $bits = $i;
        for( $j=0; $bits; $j++) {
            if( !($bits & 1)) {
                $bits = $bits >> 1;
                continue;
            }
            array_push( $set, $arr[ $j]);
            $bits = $bits >> 1;
        }

        $result = array_merge( $result, permute( $set));
    }

    return $result;

}

function permute( $items, $perms = array(), &$result = array()) {
    if( empty( $items)) {
        array_push( $result, $perms);
    } else {
        for( $i = count( $items) - 1; $i >= 0; --$i) {
             $newitems = $items;
             $newperms = $perms;
             list($foo) = array_splice($newitems, $i, 1);
             array_unshift($newperms, $foo);
             permute( $newitems, $newperms, $result);
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

function countBits( $n) {
    $count = 0;
    while( $n) {
        $count += ( $n & 1);
        $n = $n >> 1;
    }

    return $count;
}
```